# Should I post updates to my questions when they are resolved?

Tags: discussion

Is it considered 'best-practice' to come back and edit a question with the actual solution that was used in the situation?

For example, I have a question ([Playing a loyal character without it being boring](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34250/playing-a-loyal-character-without-it-being-boring)) that attracted a number of good answers of which I selected one as being the best for my situation.

In reality though, I used bits and pieces from a number of the answers to resolve my problem.

Should I just leave it with the accepted answer or should I edit my question to give a 'debrief' to what was actually done?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should not edit your question with the solution you used. That's very clearly not part of the question, and more of a forum-y thing to do.

**However:** If your solution would be a good unique answer, make it an answer of your own posted to the question! That's a very good thing to do, and increases the quality of the site in the direction of its goal of being a pile of good well-sorted answers.

(As an aside, this is a good opportunity to point out that no one should feel obligated to accept answers, especially not until you've found out if any of the answers is *actually* a solution to your problem. It's one of the reasons we no longer have "accepted answer" ratios as a stat in querent info.)

Comment: +1. If you feel bad about gaining Rep for other people's ideas, you can mark it as Community Wiki, which should technically be correct, since the answer had contributions by many different authors and you just compiled it.

Comment: With that said, the effort of actually *testing* and compiling the results of a combination of answers *is* an answer worthy of rep.